# TypeError created in Pygame within background blit code

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.6

I am trying to blit the background image on to the screen, however, I seem to keep running in to this error:

```
TypeError: unbound method update() must be called with Background instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

The error message is pointing towards this line of code:

```
Background.update()
```

I have tried moving around the blit outside and inside of the class, but the same error message keeps showing up. My guess is that this would also affect the ship code too.

This is the entire py file:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# Colors
RED     = (255,0,0)
GREEN   = (0,255,0)
BLUE    = (0,0,255)

# Screen Size
SCREEN_X = 400
SCREEN_Y = 400

# Loading Images
background = pygame.image.load('StarBackground.png')
powership = pygame.image.load('PowerShip.png')

class Ship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # Movement rate of change
    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0

    # Methods
    def __init__(self):

        # Starts the parent's constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Sets the ship's image
        self.image = powership

        # Sets the ship's rect
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Set the ship's start location
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = 0

    def move_right(self):
        self.change_x = 1

    def move_left(self):
        self.change_x = 1

    def move_up(self):
        self.change_y = 1

    def move_down(self):
        self.change_y = 1

    def stop_x(self):
        self.change_x = 0

    def stop_y(self):
        self.change_y = 0

    def update(self, screen):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)

class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):

        # Starts the parent's constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Sets the ship's image
        self.image = background

        # Sets the ship's rect
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Sets the background's starting location
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = 0

    def update(self, screen):

        screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)

def main():
    pygame.init()

    # Set the height and width of the screen
    size = [SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    pygame.display.set_caption("Space Adventure")

    # Creating the game objects
    background = Background()
    ship = Ship()

    # Close button exit code
    finished = False

    # Manages the frames per second
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # Game loop
    while not finished:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                finished = True

            keyboardInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if keyboardInput[K_RIGHT]:
                    ship.move_right()
                if keyboardInput[K_LEFT]:
                    ship.move_left()
                if keyboardInput[K_UP]:
                    ship.move_up()
                if keyboardInput[K_DOWN]:
                    ship.move_down()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if keyboardInput[K_RIGHT]:
                    ship.stop_x()
                if keyboardInput[K_LEFT]:
                    ship.stop_x()
                if keyboardInput[K_UP]:
                    ship.stop_y()
                if keyboardInput[K_DOWN]:
                    ship.stop_y()

            clock.tick(60)
            pygame.display.flip()
            Background.update()
            Ship.update()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit: Changing the update code to the following fixed the issue:

```
Background.update(screen)
Ship.update(screen)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly what the message says:

> TypeError: unbound method update() must be called with Background
>   instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

It means that you are calling the classes instead of the instances(objects). In python modules are capitalised and, by convention, instances should not.

The not capitalised lines should look as follows:

```
background.update(screen)
ship.update(screen)
```

Comment: I had to add `(screen)` at the end to make it work. Thanks for telling me that python modules should be capitalised and instances should not, that should help me avoid problems like this in the future.

Comment: @BernardoGO What a difference your answer has with mine.